# TFS API :Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.IWorkItemRowSets.TryGetRowSet

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-sdk

I have using  TFS api method to connect Team Foundation Server 2012 in my development environment .My api call working fine to connect Team Foundation server 2012 and 2010.but now i want to connect Team Foundation Server 2013 and above version . Does not support My current Api Method and  I am getting this issue .

My sample code

```
Workitemstore.GetWorkItem("1")
```

I get this error:

> Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.IWorkItemRowSets.TryGetRowSet(System.String, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.IRowSet ByRef)'.
>   StackTrace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ProxyRowSetCollectionHelper.TryGetRowSet(String name, IRowSetHelper& rowset)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Internals.WorkItemHelper.LoadRevisions(IRowSetCollectionHelper tables, IWorkItemOpenFieldDataHelper helper, Dictionary`2 latestData)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Internals.WorkItemHelper.LoadWorkItemFieldData(IRowSetCollectionHelper tables, IWorkItemOpenFieldDataHelper helper)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.LoadWorkItemFromRowSetInternal(Int32 rev, Nullable`1 asof, IWorkItemRowSets witem)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem..ctor(WorkItemStore store, Int32 id)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.GetWorkItem(Int32 id)
>      at ExportTFS.Windows.FilterForm.btnSearchImport_Click_1(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   Source: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: What function do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy` assembly is from the GAC - the GAC Version is higher than the Assembly in the Reference Assembly folder. So you get this error.

Try to copy the proxy library from GAC folder to your project and explicitly reference it.

Useful links:

- https://github.com/Code-Inside/Samples/blob/master/2013/TfsApi.WorkItems/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.ReadMe.txt
- https://mariuszgorzoch.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/method-trygetrowset-not-found/